# Angular, how to change text in a <mat-button> when toggled

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can i **change** the **text** in the **mat-button** when i toggle it?

```
<form class="example-form" style="text-align: center;" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="buttonClicked()">
  <mat-card [@myAwesomeAnimation]='state' (mouseenter)="animateMe()" (mouseleave)="animateMe()" style="padding: 2vh">
      <input type="text" class="mainInput" style="font-size: 18px;" matInput autofocus shouldLabelFloat="false" placeholder="Insert Your URL Here" autocomplete="off">
  </mat-card>
  <br>
  <button mat-raised-button color="accent"></button>

</form>
```

Comment: ps: i don't know why but i doesn't work for a form problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could have a toggle variable ?

Then use it as follow

```
<button (click)="doToggle()">{{toggle ? 'Toggled':'Not Toggled'}}</button>
```

Then in TS

```
toggle:boolean = false;

doToggle():void{
   this.toggle = !this.toggle;
   // Do some other stuff needed
 }
```

Please see [fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plqkor)

Comment: i have the button in the app component, i have to make an other component?

Comment: @Ladvace Not sure what you are asking, but the example given wont require a new component. just add the variable and method to AppComponent

Comment: i don't know why he refresh the page when i click on the button

Comment: @Ladvace Could you post a jsfiddle please?

Comment: @Ladvace I have added a fiddle to test and play with

Comment: <form class="example-form" style="text-align: center;" [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <mat-card style="padding: 2vh">
      <input type="text" class="mainInput" style="font-size: 18px;" matInput autofocus shouldLabelFloat="false" placeholder="Insert Your URL Here" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="onkeyup($event)">
  </mat-card>
  <br>
  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="clickfunction($event)">{{toggle ? 'downloading...':'Download MP3'}}</button>

</form>

Comment: and if i open the console (in the browser) it gives me errors

Comment: yes, this is the app i'm doing: [fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plqkor) and the error is:

Comment: Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

Comment: @Ladvace I suggest to create a new or change the question then because the issue is something else than what was asked for.  You could go through this [Tutorial on FormGroups](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol) and the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fYxjHY5xALoLuqaQze6u?p=preview)

Comment: tomorrow i will do it because now stackoverflow did not let me do it

Comment: Can you accept an answer regarding the current question please.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what toggle means, but if you're looking for text change, then

```
toggled: boolean = false; // Declare a boolean that holds the toggle value

<!-- Use a ternary condition -->
<button mat-raised-button (click)="toggled = !toggled" color="accent">{{toggled ? 'Toggled' : 'Not toggled'}}</button>
```

Comment: You are fast :)

Comment: i means when i click on it

Comment: What if I want the toggled text to be something that I will be sending from the typescript? That is, it will be a custom text, that will change every time. Then?

Comment: then simply use `{{ myTextToChange }}` without condition, and change the value of that variablein your typescript code or with `(click)="myTextToChange = 'Hello world'"` ...